# Accessing a variable initialized via a Factory which launches an async request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I've got a factory that sends a POST request to get some JSON key-value pairs:

```javascript
.factory('Rest', ['$resource',
function($resource) {

    // returns JSON key-value pairs, e.g. "{'foo', 'bar'}"
    return $resource('rest/get', {}, {
        get: {
            method: 'POST'
        }
    });

}])
```

I've got another factory intended to be exposed to controllers in order to access a key-value pair given its key:

```javascript
.factory('Pairs', ['Rest',
function(Rest) {

    var pairs;

    Rest.get(function(response) {
        pairs = response;
    });

    return {
        get: function(key) {
            return pairs[key];
        }
    };

}])
```

The problem is that, when I call `Pairs.get('foo')`, the `pairs` object of the `Pairs` factory is not initialized yet (since `Rest.get` is asynchronous), and thus results in a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined`:

```javascript
.controller('AnyController', ['Pairs',
function (Pairs) {

    console.log(Pairs.get('foo')); // error

}])
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You will need to return the promise for it, not the (still uninitialised) value.

Comment: @Bergi Could you provide an example?

Comment: `return Rest.get()` (not completely sure of that), and `Pairs.get().then(console.log)` should work. If not, it should at least give you the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you stated in your question, `Rest.get` is asynchronous, so your `Pairs.get` has to be asynchronous too. You can implement it as the following:

```
.factory('Pairs', ['Rest', '$q',
function(Rest, $q) {

var pairs;
var deferredList = [];

Rest.get(function(response) {
    pairs = response;
    angular.forEach(deferredList, function(o) {
        o.deferred.resolve(pairs[o.key]); // resolve saved defer object
    });
    deferredList = null; // we don't need the list anymore
});

return {
    get: function(key) {
        if (pairs) {
            return $q.when(pairs[key]); // make immediate value as a promise
        }

        var deferred = $q.defer(); // create a deferred object which will be resolved later
        deferredList.push({ // save both key and deferred object for later
            key: key,
            deferred: deferred
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
};

}])
```

Then use it like this:

```
Pairs.get('foo').then(function(value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: I was cracking my head trying to figure out how he could return the promise AND still get only the intended value and you totally nailed it! Awesome example

Comment: Excellent solution.  Note to the OP, Ye Liu doesn't address the possible need to call $apply() after your promise is resolved.  That is, of course, correct.  We can't know whether that would be an issue for your application or not.  But if you do need to call $apply(), I've some code for that in my response.

Answer (score 1):

You want to wrap your async function in a promise.  Here's how I've done something similar.
Note: safeApply triggers the $digest cycle, if necessary, so that angular can react to any data changes it might be watching.

```
 var safeApply = function (scope, fn) {
                    if (scope.$$phase || scope.$root.$$phase) { 
                        fn(); 
                    } else {  
                        scope.$apply(fn); 
                    }
                };

ret.getAll = function(type) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var where = "apm_type = '" + type + "'";

    query(type, where, function(err, response) {
        var objs = [];
        if (err) {
            safeApply($rootScope, function() { deferred.reject(err);});
        } else {
            safeApply($rootScope, function() { deferred.resolve(response);});
        }

    }); 
    return deferred.promise;
};
```